# Typo3 TCA itemsProcFunc with extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase

i try to use a extbase-action to fill a select box in my tca.

```
"config" => Array (
    "type" => "select",
    "itemsProcFunc" => 'classname->function'
}
```

i get it to call the function, but no inject-methode was called. Whats my mistake?

I think there is no extbase bootstrap call, but how can i make it happen?

Comment: If you do not get an answer here, better ask at typo3.projects.typo3v4mcv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to create a "legacy" PHP Class that calls extbase internally.